# Remove/Change specific Html tags NotePad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, html, find-and-replace, tags

i have found many similar posts, but non of them answers my question.
I would like to replace/remove/change open and close tag with a specific key word. in this case i am trying to remove all tags whit href="#" in it....

```
<a href="#">leave this text</a>
<a class="" id="" href="#">leave this text too</a>

<a href="http://......">Dont remove this tag!</a>
```

I have this code, but i cant figure out how to leave the text...

```
find: <a[^h]*href="#"[^>]*> (skip content) </a>
replace: (same content)
or
replace: <a href="somthing"> (same content) </a>
```

Comment: By note++ you mean notepad++?

Comment: Yes, im sorry. NotePad++

Comment: That was too easy! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I am trying to remove all tags containing `href="#"`

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `<a .*?href="#">(.*?)</a>`
- Set "Replace with" to `\1`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

**Before**:

```
<a href="#">leave this text</a>
<a class="" id="" href="#">leave this text too</a>
<a href="http://......">Dont remove this tag!</a>
```

**After**:

```
leave this text
leave this text too
<a href="http://......">Dont remove this tag!</a>
```

As pointed out by [AFH](https://superuser.com/users/327367/afh) in a comment, there is a better regular expression that will catch expression that were not included in the sample data.

- Set "Find what" to `<a .*?href="#" .*?>(.*?)</a>`

  This will match lines where there are clauses **after** the `href="#"` (and before the first matching `>`).

  Note:

  It will fail to work correctly if there are any `>`s in the value field of a subsequent clause (before the `>` matching `<a`)

---

#### Further reading

- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)

Comment: I can't see any reason why your search string would not have worked with the examples the questioner gave, although his answer below does allow for clauses after the `href` as well as before: for this you would need `<a .*?href="#" .*?>(.*?)</a>`. In fact, this should be a better solution, as his would fail if there were another clause containing `h` before the `href` (eg in the `class` or `id` value). Both would fail if there were `>` in the value field of a subsequent clause, and I see no easy fix for this (unlikely) case.

Comment: @AFH Agree with all of the above. However, my answer worked with the data the OP provided as input. I will add a note with your regular expression just for completeness. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you David for the answer!
But actually the code: `<a .*?href="#">(.*?)</a>` did not found any attributes in my file. It may be because of some other configurations or different versions of notepad++.
I had to use this code:

```
 Find:    <a[^h]*href="#"[^>]*>(.*?)</a>
 Replace: <a href="new_url">\1</a>
```

Comment: My answer was correct with the data you provided as input. I don't believe the version of Notepad++ will make any difference with this kind of regular expression.